# suggested edits are stuck

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

I've been reviewing suggested edits over the past several minutes, and the same edits have been reappearing multiple times (5+) after performing an action on them. I even check my action was "saved," and it reappears a few suggested edits later. What gives?

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2310369 Approved
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2310394
  Rejected as "too minor"

Comment: Um... those links are 2 different suggestions

Comment: Those are the two edits that kept reappearing.

Comment: Could you link to the reappearances?

Comment: Link to them? As in the links in my question aren't sufficient?

Comment: No, you only linked to them once. You said that you saw them 5 times or more, right? Could you link to the next times you saw them?

Comment: They had the same URL each time they reappeared.

Comment: Oh, so you've seen the same URL more than once in the queue? Okay,  well that's really odd... (+1)

Comment: That's what I'm saying.

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.  Also, damn you for piquing my curiosity and luring me back into the Suggested Edit queue...

Comment: @LBT I will pay you 1000 Yen for your troubles.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - you don't have to do that; besides, I only accept Unicorn-bucks

Comment: Are you using the back button in your Chrome browser?  You'll get an old copy of the page, if you're doing that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Nope. I would submit the edit and it would take me right back to it as if it was my first review. So I would review edit 1, 2, then 3 would recycle 5 times, review 4, 5, then 6 would recycle 5 times, review 7, 8 and 6 would reappear. I know that they can reappear in the same queue if another edit takes place, but it's the recycling of the same edit that left me curious.

Comment: You mean *approve* the edit, right?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yep (or reject).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I believe the back button will show you the results, not acutally go back.